# Cannot install the latest version of an R package

Tags: r, rstudio

I am interested in using [ClickStream](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/clickstream/versions/1.3.0) R package, particularly version 1.3.0. I have installed it with:

```
install.packages("clickstream")
```

However, the version that was downloaded is 1.1.9, which is missing several important functions. I have tried to updated the package within R-studio using `Tools -> Check for Package Updates`, but it says all packages are up to date. The version of R-studio is 1.1.453.

I just cannot figure out what I am supposed to do to automatically download the latest version of this package. Any help?

Comment: What did you try? What happened? Was there an error message? Was it in a clean R session? What version of R do you have? What version of RStudio do you have?

Comment: @CalumYou I have added the details, sorry! I did not receive any errors. Just R-studio automatically downloads the previous version instead of the latest.

Comment: It's the version of R that matters, not RStudio. What does typing `R.version` in the console and pressing Enter give you, for major and minor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably attempting to install from a repository that is out-of-date. Going to the CRAN page for clickstream we see that it has version 1.3.0 for all the major branches of R. There was a time when installing RStudio resulted in getting an out-of-date version of R, which then required that one install an up-to-date version of R. I think they also had a "matching" repo for that version so you wouldn't get a warning message:

```
# Check your R version
R.version$version.string
#[1] "R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)"          #result if all is well

URL for CRAN page
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clickstream/index.html
```

It has several dependencies:

```
Depends:    R (≥ 3.0.1), methods, igraph, stats, utils, reshape2, data.table, MASS
Imports:    plyr, Rsolnp, arules, linprog, ggplot2, ClickClust, parallel
```

You can figure out where you are getting packages with:

```
options()$repos
                        CRAN 
"http://cloud.r-project.org"
```